# How to stop a multi-threaded Python script from outside

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a Python program that uses multiple daemon threads. I want to stop the program from outside, preferably from another Python script.

I've tried with `kill <pid>` from shell, just for a test, but it doesn't work with multi-threaded scripts.

One way would be to make the program check some file every n-seconds as a flag for termination. I'm sure there's some better way I can do this.

Note that I'd like to stop the program cleanly, so some message from outside in a form of an exception would be ideal, I think.

**EDIT**:
Here's an example of how I did it at the moment:

```
try:
    open('myprog.lck', 'w').close()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            open('myprog.lck').close()
        except IOError:
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'MyProgram terminated.'
```

Deleting file `myprog.lck` will cause the script to stop. Is the example above bad way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried having `kill` send a signal other than the default `TERM`? If a process is really misbehaving you can always use `KILL` (`kill -KILL <pid>`).

Comment: Do you mean multiprocess or multithreaded?

Comment: @icktoofay The program is running perfectly fine, I just want to be able to stop or restart the program from another Python script. I'll edit the question to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Use the poison pill technique. Upon receipt of a pill (a special message) your program must handle it and die.. The way you're doing it its ok, but for something more elegant, you should implement a kind of communication between your "killing script" and your main program. For a start, have a look in the standard library for [Interprocess Communication and Networking](http://docs.python.org/library/ipc.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would install a signal handler as described in http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/signal/index.html#signals-and-threads

You can enter `kill -l` in your shell to get a list of available signals.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to kill it from the shell with `kill -9 <pid>`.